# SceneManager() =default; is a deleted function

Tags: c++11

```
class SceneManager{
public:
SceneManager() = default;
~SceneManager() = default;
}
class Engine{
Engine() : _logger("Engine"){} << ERROR
private:
SceneManager s;
Logger mutable logger; // has only a constructor Logger(const std::string& name)
}
```

I have read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx and wondered why I was not able compile my code where I had a SceneManager _sceneManager member variable and the tooltip in Visual Studio 2013 tells me "the default constructor of SceneManager can not be referenced - it is a deleted function".

The code above sadly is no SCCNE as I am unable to find out what causes the error as I expect the =default keyword to do nothing different than simply providing SceneManager(); as I do not see a reason for the constructor to not be generated.

Under which circumstances is a =default declared constructor deleted?

> The problem can obviously be resolved by removing =default.

This is oviously wrong. See the selected answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 12.1 Constructors [class.ctor]/p4:

A defaulted default constructor for class `X` is defined as deleted if:

- `X` is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor,
- any non-static data member with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* is of reference type,
- any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* does not have a user-provided default constructor,
- `X` is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
- `X` is a non-union class and all members of any anonymous union member are of const-qualified type
  (or array thereof),
- any potentially constructed subobject, except for a non-static data member with a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, has class type `M` (or array thereof) and either `M` has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) as applied to M’s default constructor results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor, or
- any potentially constructed subobject has a type with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor.

> The problem can obviously be resolved by removing =default.

Not in any way I currently foresee with a C++11/14 conforming compiler, except for the possibility that in doing so, the default constructor signature becomes unprovided as opposed to user-declared and compiler-provided as deleted.  This latter possibility exists if some other `SceneManager` constructor is user-declared.

Comment: Thank you very much, it took me quite a while to understand the reason but I think it is 6). As Logger mutable _logger contains no default construct it is obvious that this can not compile as how should it know the parameter for the constructor of _logger! This was a really helpful and wonderful answer!